# How do you strip everything after a pattern in a filename?

Tags: bash, quoting, parameter-expansion

Edit:
I simply need to strip the `.gz`

```
SUBMIT joust_aallgeier_attempt_2015-11-12-20-37-40_project04.tar.gz
```

These are gunzipped already. 
I need `project.tar` output
I have the following stripping the first portion.

```
filename=${j##*_}
```

Comment: Can you give examples of files where it doesn't work? It looks like it should work.

Comment: Sorry a logic issue had me blaming the wrong thing.  I need to strip .gz from the end.

Comment: Holy jibbers I need to learn why " " is required on vars this is the second time I was beating me head against the wall for something like this not working. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With bash's [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
filename="SUBMIT joust_aallgeier_attempt_2015-11-12-20-37-40_project04.tar.gz"
stripped="${filename##*_}"
stripped="${stripped%.gz}"
echo "$stripped"
```

Output:

```
project04.tar
```